# Spring Security: AuthenticationFailureCredentialsExpiredEvent not fired

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am using spring.security.version = 3.1.0.RELEASE. The problem I am having is that for some reason AuthenticationFailureCredentialsExpiredEvent is not fired.

While debugging the code I found that AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider do display in the console that "User account credentials have expired". But I am still baffling as to why the event in concern is not triggered.

Here is my code:

```
class JpaUserDetails implements UserDetails {
...
...
   @Override
   public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
       if (some logic) {
           return true;
       }
       else {
           return false;
       }
   }
}
```

I do see AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider displaying in the console "User account credentials have expired" from the following lines of spring code:

```
public abstract class AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider, InitilizeBean, MessageSourceAware {
...
...
    private class DefaultPostAuthenticationChecks implements UserDetailsChecker {
        public void check(UserDetails user) {
            if(!user.isCredentialsNonExpired()) {
                logger.debug("User account credentials have expired");
                throw new CredentialsExpiredException(message.getMessage(
                          "AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.credentialsExpired",
                          "User credentials have expired"), user);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is that when the user credentials have expired, I am expecting the Spring to generate the event AuthenticationFailureCredentialsExpiredEvent which I am handling in the following way:

```
class SecurityEventDispatcher implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationEvent> {
    final List<SecurityEventListener> listeners = new ArrayList<SecurityEventListener>();

    public void registerListener(SecurityEventListener listener) {
        this.listener.add(listener);
    }

    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
        for (SecurityEventListener listener : this.listeners) {
            if(listener.canHandle(event)) {
                listener.handle(event);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I am handling the login failure event:

```
public class LoginFailedEvent extends SecurityEventListener {

    @Override
    public boolean canHandle(Object event) {
        if(event instanceof AbstractAuthenticationFailureEvent) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(Object event) {
        if (event instanceof AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent) {
            // do something
        }

        if (event instanceof AuthenticationFailureCredentialsExpiredEvent) {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

The issue as I mentioned before is that AuthenticationFailureCredentialsExpiredEvent is never fired. I have tested the AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent which works fine.

This is what I get in event for bad credentials: (which is working fine)

> org.springframework.security.authentication.event.AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent

This is what I get in event for expired password:

> ServletRequestHandledEvent: url=[/app/loginFailure] with failureCause = null

Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer to this question, since there isn't any much literature out there regarding the issue.

> You probably need to set the ProviderManager's
>   ('s) eventPublisher to be something other than
>   NullEventPublisher. There is not a simple way to do this via the
>    tag, so you will want to create the
>   AuthenticationProvider using standard beans configuration and inject
>   it into a standard Spring Bean for the ProviderManager.
>
> Rob Winch - Spring Security Lead

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is running into this issue, just upgrade the spring security to 3.1.2 or +, the issue is fixed.

Comment: Can you share the `security-context.xml` file

Answer (score 0):

(Applies to Spring Security 5)

Spring's default  publisher is  the `NullEventPublisher`. This will effectively publish nothing.To get events please configure a

```
import org.springframework.security.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher;


@Bean
public DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher defaultAuthenticationEventPublisher() {
   return new DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher();
}
```

Now the events a published and one can just consume them as any other event:

```
@EventListener
public void logAuditEvents(AbstractAuthenticationEvent event) {
   ...
}
```

and

```
@EventListener
public void logAuditEvents(AbstractAuthorizationEvent event) {
   ...
}
```